# Tag search not working after permalink structure change

Tags: permalinks, tags

I recently changed my permalink structure from the default one /?p=123 to Post name, /sample-post/.
That went well except that now the tag search doesn't work.

Previously, when I clicked on the tag in the tag cloud, I would get /?tag=tag-name, and it worked.
Now the structure is /tag/tag-name, and when clicking on it, it doesn't list the posts with that tag, but instead, it redirects to the post that has that tag in its title.

This is my tag cloud:

```
<?php wp_tag_cloud(array(
                   'smallest' => 15,
                   'largest' => 15,
                   'unit' => 'px',
                   'number' => 45,
                   'orderby'  => 'name',  alphabetically
                   'order' => 'ASC', ascending order
                   'taxonomy' => 'post_tag'
                   )); ?>
```

I can't post comments, so:
@TheDeadMedic Thanks for replying.

The settings are: Front page displays: Your latest posts. Yes, the permalink is %postname%, but the same thing happens with any other permalink settings.

Comment: On the Settings > Permalinks page, is the "Tag base" field empty?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Thank you for your reply. Yes, it is empty.
So, clicking on a tag will redirect me to the post that has that tag name in its title, or give me "page not found", if there is no such post.

Comment: And I assume your permalink structure is `/%postname%/`? Under Settings > Reading, what are your "Front page displays" settings?